# How to calculate the ABV of an alcohol-infused watermelon?

Tags: geometry, volume

I am trying to calculate the approximate ABV (alcohol by volume) of a watermelon that I am saturating with vodka.

**Details**

If I were to cut the watermelon in half length-wise, its face would be an approximate oval (a little rounder, but I mostly need a ball-park) with a length of 12 inches and width of 8 inches. It weighs about 8 pounds. [Watermelon.org](http://www.watermelon.org/FoodService/Watermelon-Basics) suggests that a watermelon is 70% flesh and 30% rind. I assume that the rind will still absorb some of the alcohol, but at a diminished rate. For this question, I will assume that the rind absorption rate will be 50% that of the flesh. (I don't know if it is relevant or not, but that website also states that watermelon is 92% water.)

I will be using a 25.3 fl oz (750 ml) bottle of 40% abv vodka. I will assume that 100% of the vodka will be absorbed by the flesh and rind and it will be evenly distributed throughout.

**Problem**

I know that the equation to calculate the volume for a prolate ellipsoid is [4/3π(1/2*length)((1/2*width)^2)](http://www.web-formulas.com/Math_Formulas/Geometry_Volume_of_Ellipsoid.aspx), which for my watermelon is 4/3π*6*4*4 ≈ 402 in^3. This is where things get a little hazy and since I would rather not have someone getting alcohol posisioning on my head, I figured it would be time to ask the professional here at Math.SE. I am assuming that 280.4 in^3 (402*.7) would be flesh and 120.6 in^3 (402*.3) would be rind, but I am at a complete loss for how to proceed with calculating ABV from this information.

If any of my assumptions or calculations appear incorrect, please let me know and explain -- after all, I am here to learn.

Comment: Why calculate the ABV? You know how much vodka you are putting in. If you are cutting the vodka into pieces just work out how much vodka is in each piece. (You could cut the pieces so that each one is the same as a shot of vodka.)

Comment: @smcc The idea is to make it like in [this picture](http://img-aws.ehowcdn.com/640/cme/photography.prod.demandstudios.com/b38e54e3-6a8a-40d5-a90b-70c39ecbeee8.jpg) and then cut it into wedges and serve. Since the wedges would all be varying sizes, it would be hard to do. I do really like the idea of "watermelon shots" though! Cubes of watemelon that double as a shot sounds fantastic.

Comment: @smcc Also, if I (or someone else) wanted to make multiple watermelons of various alcohol levels, it seems that it would be good to have a way to provide a number so people can compare them. For example, saying Watermelon A is 20% abv and Watermelon B is 15% abv provides people with a little clearer idea than just saying Watermelon A has a bit more vodka in it or Watermelon B was a bit bigger so its less alcoholic. I'm trying to make it concrete as possible.

Comment: If you assume that the ABV of the rind will be half the ABV of the flesh, then you're solving the equation:$$(\text{volume of flesh})\times x + (\text{volume of rind})\times x/2 = (\text{volume of alcohol added})$$ where $x$ is the ABV of the flesh and $x/2$ is the ABV of the rind. That said, I'm not sure this is the proper calculation - exactly how the alcohol diffuses into the watermelon might be complicated, and depend on many hard to know variables - e.g. what if the alcohol doesn't migrate far from the bottle? You might have better luck devising a way to measure this experimentally.

Comment: 1 in^3 ≃ 16.387 ml, so 750 ml ≃ 45.77 in^3. Since it is 40% ABV, you have 0.40×45.77in^3 ≃ 18.3 in^3 of pure alcohol. If all of it were absorbed into the flesh, you'd have 100%×18.3/280.4 ≃ 6.5% ABV in the flesh, assuming the amount of water corresponding to the amount of pure alcohol evaporates (since I don't think the watermelon *expands*; might get heavier, though -- haven't weighed mine).  If the water does not evaporate, or some of the alcohol is absorbed by the rind, your ABV will be lower (since volume is larger). So, 6.5% at most. It's in the lager to porter range, on the beer scale.

Comment: And just because I too like spiked watermelon (and un-spiked watermelon, too), and grapes (raisins are nice, especially in glühwine, but given time, they become like brown grapes, and can absorb a *deceptively high* amount of alcohol), doesn't make us alcoholics. Ahem. So, perhaps change the title from *"an alcoholic watermelon"* to *"an alcohol-infused watermelon"*?

Comment: @NominalAnimal Edit done. And thanks! I'd certainly +1 your comment as an answer as it certainly gets me closer to a definitive answer and gives me a couple more numbers to play around with. I haven't looked too closely, but in combination with the comment from @ MiloBrandt, it may be just what I need.

Comment: @MiloBrandt I may put together some sort of jerry-rigged injection system with multiple points of entry so I am just assuming uniform distribution for this question, but that is certainly something to keep in mind for others actually making one of these. A way to measure it would probably be cool and fun, but a fairly quick calculation would definitely be useful for anyone who wants a close estimation based on a couple quick measurements.

Comment: For safety, you certainly want to find out the *maximum* amount of alcohol by volume. Calculate the volume of pure alcohol you infused, and divide that by the volume of final edibles, and you get an estimate of the maximum ABV, assuming even distribution. Watermelon flesh is quite uniform, so given enough time, it will absorb the alcohol quite evenly. I'd simply taste test to verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the volume of the watermelon by submersing it in some known volume of water $x$ and then measuring the volume again $y$. The volume of the watermelon is $V=y-x$ (let us suppose we measure volume in mL)

[image]
<sub>(source: [archimedespalimpsest.org](http://archimedespalimpsest.org/images/kaltoon/page-1.jpg))</sub>

According to the figures given , $70\%$ is flesh and $30\%$ rind (by weight). If the absorption rate of rind is $50\%$ that of flesh, then the proportion of the total vodka that ends up in the flesh, $f$, satisfies

$$\frac{f}{0.7}=\frac{(1-f)}{0.5(0.3)}$$

so that $f=14/17\approx 0.82$.

If the vodka is proportion $a$ alcohol and the volume of vodka added is $v$, then the percentage of alcohol in the rind of the watermelon (by volume) is:

$$\frac{avf}{0.7V}.$$

So if $a=0.4$, $v=750$mL and $f=0.82$ we get

$$\frac{0.4(750)(0.82)}{0.7V}\approx \frac{351}{V}$$

Your calculations gave a volume $V$ of watermelon of about $6588$mL. The ABV would then be about $0.053$, or $5.3\%$.

If you want an ABV of $w$ for a watermelon of volume $V$, you should add a volume $2.125wV$ of $40\%$ vodka.

Comment: The question doesn't ask for the volume of the watermelon. The author has already calculated that.

Comment: Yes, but he didn't need to do it the way he did. Once he knows the volume of the watermelon, how much is likely to be rind, and how much alcohol is being added it is very simple to approximate the ABV.

Comment: The comic confuses me. What does volume have to do with whether there is silver mixed with the crown? Wouldn't a pure gold crown have the same volume as a pure silver one made from the same mold? Shouldn't Archie be more interested in density or malleability or some other physical property?

Comment: @Pants: I don't know the actual truth behind the Archimedes legend (nor do I know if *anyone* knows it), but because silver and gold have different densities (gold being denser by a ratio of about two-to-one), it's not possible for the two crowns to have both the same volume *and* the same weight.  Presumably the crown was first weighed as a first check of genuineness, and passed, but then when it didn't also pass the check of volume, that's when it hit the fan.  (If only the goldsmith had added other material altogether, that would have given him plausible deniability.)

Comment: @BrianTung That's where they lost me! They seem to have skipped a panel or two in the middle showing the weight test. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: @smcc Great edit! As soon as I stick around long enough to get at least 15 rep, expect a +1 from me. I had just ran the numbers with the equations Milo and Nominal helped with in the comments on the OP and got 5.4%, so with rounding, this seems to check out. I feel silly now for not realizing that I already had 2 ABVs (40% of liquid volume and 0% of watermelon volume) and was just a little algebra away from figuring it out on my own.